# How to select only not null objects from list

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a list of objects of type Pump, each one of them holding a reference to an object of type Valve, exposed through its property Valve.

```
Public Class Pump

    Private _valve As Valve 'may be Nothing

    Public ReadOnly Property Valve() As Valve
        Get
            Return _valve 
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

However, the valve can exist or just be Nothing.

**It there an easy way to select all the valves and put them in a list?**

I tried this:

```
_pumps.Select(Of Valve)(Function(p As Pump) p.Valve).ToList
```

But I get a list with some of the objects being Nothing, since there was no valve asigned to the correspondent pump.

I have finally done this:

```
Dim valves As New List(Of Valve)
    For Each p As PumpIn _pumps
        If p.Valve IsNot Nothing Then
            valves.Add(p.Valve)
        End If
    Next
```

But I was wondering if there is a more compact way of doing it:

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will help:

```
_pumps.Where(Function(p) p.Valve IsNot Nothing).Select(Of Valve)(Function(p As Pump) p.Valve).ToList
```

Comment: The Where clause should check for null valve not null pump.

Comment: @meta-knight You were right and i changed it, though i think a downvote was a bit too harsh in this case. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you were on the right track and now it's fixed. Upvoted instead :-) One more thing to note, you can just write `.Select(Function(p) p.Valve)` without the `(Of Valve)` and `As Pump` parts which are superfluous.

Comment: @meta-knight I know and this is how i would write it, but i wanted to keep the changes to the minimum.